# camera2 output to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, google-vision

I'm trying to use [Google Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview) with the camera2 module and I'm having a lot of trouble.

I'm using Google's [android-Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) example code as a base. I've modified it to include the following callback:

**Camera2VideoFragment.java**

```
OnCameraImageAvailable mCameraImageCallback;

public interface OnCameraImageAvailable {
    void onCameraImageAvailable(Image image);
}


ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mImageAvailable = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

        Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        if (image == null)
            return;

        mCameraImageCallback.onCameraImageAvailable(image);

        image.close();
    }
};
```

That way any fragment including `Camera2VideoFragment.java` can get access to its images.

Now, The Barcode API only accepts `Bitmap` images, but I'm unable to convert `YUV_420_888` to Bitmap. Instead, I changed the `imageReader`'s file format to `JPEG` and ran the following conversion code:

```
    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
    buffer.rewind();
    byte[] data = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
    buffer.get(data);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

This worked but the framerate drop of feeding `JPEG` data to the `imageReader` was significant. I'm wondering if anyone has worked around this issue before.

Comment: Your code helped me solve the problem that I could not otherwise. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes I have the same problem and I was not able to find better solution. In addition to this, on some Qualcom Camera chips, this causes the camera capture to stop working at all and the only way to recover is the device reboot. Unfortunately, even with the Camera 2, the Android team only cares about the main stream users (who display the preview directly to the surface). They do not seem to case much about those who need the camera to be working completely without ANY UI (or I just failed to find such a solution).

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but hopefully still helpful.

As *Ezequiel Adrian* on his [Example](https://github.com/EzequielAdrianM/Camera2Vision) has explained the conversion of   YUV_420_888 into one of the supported formats (In his case NV21), you can do the similar thing to get your Bitmap output:

```
private byte[] convertYUV420888ToNV21(Image imgYUV420) {
// Converting YUV_420_888 data to YUV_420_SP (NV21).
byte[] data;
ByteBuffer buffer0 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
ByteBuffer buffer2 = imgYUV420.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
int buffer0_size = buffer0.remaining();
int buffer2_size = buffer2.remaining();
data = new byte[buffer0_size + buffer2_size];
buffer0.get(data, 0, buffer0_size);
buffer2.get(data, buffer0_size, buffer2_size);
return data;}
```

Then you can convert the result into Bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: BitmapFactory was unable to generate a bitmap using the method.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am facing the same issue where in the BitmapFactory is returning null

Comment: For me, this does not work either. IMU, all the formates except of JPEG have two properties in common: They are device specific and BitmapFactory CANNOT decode it :(